# QGIS, Is there a way to import 400 SVG files to the symbol list all in one go?

Tags: qgis, svg

I need to import 400 SVG as SVG Markers to the QGIS styles library. I know how to do it one by one but I need a way to import all of them in one go...

Is there a way?

I am in QGIS 2.8.2. Wien.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note that I use QGIS 2.6.1)

If they're all in a single folder, you can add the PATH to your SVG directory in QGIS:

*Settings* > *Options* > *System* > *SVG paths*:

[image: SVG path]

Alternatively, you can create a folder called "svg" in your ".qgis2" directory and place all your svg files there:

```
C:\Users\(your user name)\.qgis2
```

Hope this helps!